# PlantUML extension for Visual Studio Code on Windows only working with sequence diagrams

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, plantuml

I installed the [PlantUML extension (by jebbs)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml) in Visual Studio Code for Windows and everything is working perfectly for **sequence** diagrams.

However when I try to render a **class** diagram I get the message:

> Dot Executable: \opt\local\bin\dot
>   File does not exist
>   Cannot find Graphviz

Screencap of full error message:

[image: Dot Executable does not exist error]

When I try the example `@startuml testdot @enduml` code specified I get the following error:

> The environment variable GRAPHVIZ_DOT has been set to /opt/local/bin/dot
>   Dot executable is \opt\local\bin\dot

Screencap of full error message:

[image: GRAPHVIZ_DOT has been set error]

Any ideas where this has been specified such that I can override it (assuming this is what the problem is)? It hasn't been added to the system or user environment variables that I can see.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The GRAPHVIZ_DOT environment variable is specified in File > Preferences > Settings > Plantuml: Command Args. Click on the link to "Edit in settings.json".

[image: Settings dialog]

[image: settings.json]

**Additionally** the VSCode PlantUML extension doesn't appear to include the graphviz "dot.exe" executable, so this needs to be downloaded and installed (e.g. via chocolatey OR download and unzip from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html)

Following this, update the path and save.

```
{
    "plantuml.commandArgs": [
        "-DGRAPHVIZ_DOT=D:\\Tools\\graphviz-2.38\\release\\bin\\dot.exe",
    ]
}
```

Also see https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml/issues/94

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to fix the graphviz dot: null issue:

`From VSC: Goto EXTENSIONS: MARKETPLACE` ( you can find the option on the left side)

[image]

Select the graphviz extension that you have installed e.g. @ext:tintinweb.graphviz-interactive-preview

Click the Settings

```
Graphviz-interactive-preview: Render Lock  (Uncheck this one)
Graphviz-interactive-preview: Render Lock Additional Timeout: -1
```

If VSC is on Windows, then create a variable pointing to the location where dot.exe of graphviz has been installed.

[image]

Comment: For those attempting to utilise PlantUML from the `toolbox` on Fedora Silverblue/Kinoite, the absence of `graphviz` is the problem. Just install `graphviz` by running `sudo dnf install graphviz` and the errors will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The prerequisite of PlantUML is Java and Graphviz (https://plantuml.com/starting)

> You need these things to run PlantUML: Java Graphviz (optional if you
> only need sequence diagrams and activity (beta) diagrams)

, in Windows machine, we can download and extract the Graphviz and then put it in the user path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on linux, rigth now [@Claire Furney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265167/claire-furney)'s answer didn't work for me. After installing the required tool you need to specify `dot` path correct.

[Official documentation](https://plantuml.com/graphviz-dot) is correct now. Go there and install by following any of these:

Fedora packages: `sudo yum install graphviz`

Ubuntu packages: `sudo apt install graphviz`

Debian packages: `sudo apt install graphviz`

then add dot variable like following:

```
{
  "plantuml.commandArgs": [
    "-DGRAPHVIZ_DOT=/usr/bin/dot",
  ]
}
```

After that it must work.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, it should like the below:

"-DGRAPHVIZ_DOT=/opt/homebrew/bin/dot"